# Log MDC keys using logback, with fixed width, only if they have a value

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, mdc

How can I log the value of multiple MDC keys with logback, depending on wheter these MDC keys have a value?

Certain threads have MDC information added like this:

```
MDC.put("action", "MyActionName");
log.debug ("something happened during an action")
```

other threads have MDC information like this:

```
MDC.put("section", "abc");
MDC.put("subsection", "def");
MDC.put("subsubsection", "ghi");
log.debug ("something happened in a subsubsection")
```

I want a log where the first log message is prefixed with "MyActionName" and the second log message is prefixed with "abc def ghi". The MDC values should be printed with fixed width.

```
00:00 [Thread1] MyActionName - something happened during an action
00:01 [Thread2] abc def ghi  - something happened in a subsubsection
```

These log lines correspond to the patterns

```xml
<pattern>%d{HH:mm} [%thread] %12.-12mdc{action} - %msg%n</pattern>
<pattern>%d{HH:mm} [%thread] %3.-3mdc{section} %3.-3mdc{subsection} %3.-3mdc{subsubsection} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

How can I combine these two log format patterns into a single pattern that works in both cases?

I know that I can define a [default value](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables) when a MDC key is not available with `:-`, and that this default value can in turn contain other variables. So something like this should work:

```xml
<pattern>%d{HH:mm} [%thread] %12.-12mdc{action:-(%3.-3mdc{section} %3.-3mdc{subsection} %3.-3mdc{subsubsection})} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

But this does not work, it just prints the string `%3.-3mdc{section..." in the log, if the mdc key "action" is not defined.

The fallback MDC expressions are not evaluated, no matter what combination of `:-`, `()` and `${}` I try.